# Accessing properties attribute inside the get accessor

Tags: c#, .net, custom-attributes

Am creating a custom attribute for my properties and was wondering if anyone know how i could access the the value of the Attribute inside of the get accessor.

```
public class MyClass
{
    [Guid("{2017ECDA-2B1B-45A9-A321-49EA70943F6D}")]
    public string MyProperty
    {
        get { return "value loaded from guid"; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why can’t you just return the GUID from the property? Why do you need to use a custom attribute?

Comment: @Timwi, the only benefit I could see from an attribute is that you could inspect it without an instance of the class constructed, but users of the class could also get it from a live instance without having to use reflection directly.  Not sure if that's sufficiently beneficial to warrant the complexity.

Comment: Its a simplified example, the value returned will be a value loaded from the Guid, not return the Guid itself.

Comment: That still doesn’t explain why you need the custom attribute and why you can’t just put the GUID right in the code.

Comment: I could, but am looking for one place where I can store the Guid and that i can access from multiple places, e.g. get, set and externally to the class. Have been storing the Guids in a constants file but it is getting quite large so am looking for a more manageable solution.

Comment: How about a static readonly field? Or a constant?

Comment: Yeah I've thought about them both (currently using constants) but they are getting messy and hard to manage littered in the code. Am looking for a cleaner way to implement these properties as this will be part of a framework so want it to be as easy as possible for a developer to create a class and access the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can retrieve the property and then its custom attributes via reflection, like this:

```
// Get the property
var property = typeof(MyClass).GetProperty("MyProperty");

// Get the attributes of type “GuidAttribute”
var attributes = property.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(GuidAttribute), true);

// If there is an attribute of that type, return its value
if (attributes.Length > 0)
    return ((GuidAttribute) attributes[0]).Value;

// Otherwise, we’re out of luck!
return null;
```

Answer (score 1):

Setting aside the wisdom of such a thing...

```
public string MyProperty
{
    get
    {
        return this.GetType().GetProperty("MyProperty").GetCustomAttributes(typeof(GuidAttribute), true).OfType<GuidAttribute>().First().Value;
    }
}
```